# Safely transfer credit from one user to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, concurrency

I'm working on a website in which I use Asp.Net MVC with Entity Framework 6. Each user has a credit and sometimes users can transfer their credit to other users. The simple approach would be this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //....
    public decimal Credit { get; set; }
}

var user1 = await db.Users.FindAsync(id1);
var user2 = await db.Users.FindAsync(id2);
user1.Credit -= amount;
user2.Credit += amount;

await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

However, I think this will be vulnerable to concurrency issues. For instance, what if 2 users transfer to a user at the exact same time?

Since we will be using real money as credit in the website, what is the most secure and fail-proof approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Vulnerable to concurrency ??? Have you tested ? because i do theses kind of thing and i'm going to change it immediatly if theres is a risk of incoherence...

Comment: i thought ASYNC was exactly made for these kind of things, But also, if there is a money transaction in this you should have a transaction table with transaction IDs so you can trace everything...

Comment: You can configure a concurrency column in your model so that updates are protected. You could have a `DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }` property.

Answer (score 1):

By default EntityFramework will wrap `SaveChanges()` into a transaction. so your changes will either success or or fail together.

What you can do:

### A transaction wrapper

1. You can explicitly wrap your code into a TransactionScope()

   using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
           {
               // Code that needs to work atomically in a transaction 
           }

Or

### A transaction table

2. Use a better database design that store transactions instead of final state

This is the bank's approach. store a debit from an account and a credit into another account whenever a transaction occurs.

- take -50 from Joe
- put +50 to Jane

Then when you query for a user's balance, you aggregate the final balance based on the Sum of all their transactions (pretty easy for any DBMS that supports SQL)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please give me a code sample for 2nd option? I'm more interested in banks' approach to this

Comment: Also, if there are lots of transaction rows for a user, wouldn't that introduce an overhead to the website after a while? wouldn't it slow the queries down?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Have your process remove the money from the old account first, then confirm the transaction was posted to the old account then apply the funds to the new account.
2. Record a serial number on each transfer, and confirm when posted to their account that the transaction has the proper serial number for that transaction.  This is just good practice so you can have a log as well of every transfer.
3. After posting the debt to the source account, confirm the account balance is not negative.  If it is, cancel the transaction.  This prevents several debits against an existing balance then ends up being negative after each debt is applied to the source account (an added safety catch).  Also, make sure the amount being transferred is positive.  An easy hacker scam is to transfer a negative amount from someone else's account (increasing the hacker's account as a result).

There are many ways to do this manually if you don't trust the frame work your using, and many of these checks should be done just to reduce the fraud risk.

You can lock both records, do your transfer, then unlock both records.  Before locking, making sure they are not already locked.  That way, both records are locked until the transaction completes.

Nothing replaces the need for transaction logs, IMHO.

Comment: I imagine the framework should be able to handle things like this. Trying to come up with manual solutions for things like this will usually introduce more problems itself. Doesn't the EF have anything regarding this?